# Google plus doesn't share description

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, share

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

I refered this link..

When I tried to share the event title, image and description. I am unable to share event description.

1. Schema.org microdata
2. Open Graph protocol
3. Title and meta "description" tags

I used above all three methods to share the event description. If any one knows please share the info..

Comment: We won't be able to suggest fixes without seeing a live version of the page you are having issues with.

Comment: please post example code for 1 & 2     

For 3. this is the description of the page not the event - you would need the entire page to be about the event for it to show in serach results, and it would not indicate that it was an event or any other type of item than an ordinary webpage

Comment: When i tried to share events in google plus. It shows description but it didn't share on google plus.